# Selenium does not recognize pop up as existing

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Original code credit: Omer Sakarya and Ken Jee.

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    obj = driver.switch_to.alert
    obj.dismiss()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

Unfortunately, the pop-up stays on the screen and 30 seconds passes resulting in a time-out. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
   url='https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/' + keyword + '-jobs- 
   SRCH_KO0,14.htm'
   driver.get(url)
   jobs = []


    try:
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,  '[data- 
    selected="true"]').click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        pass


    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.alert_is_present())
        obj=driver.switch_to.alert
        obj.dismiss()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('x out failed')
        pass
```

Comment: which website you are trying to bypass the pop-up window?

Comment: Is the popup an iframe? You have to switch to the iframe before being able to close it.

Comment: Can you supply a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @VaeJiang glassdoor. Should be the same pop-up that occurs when navigating anywhere signed out.

Comment: @dosas Edited the comment to reflect a bit more-lmk if you have any ideas, thanks!

Comment: @steven01804 not an iframe from what I can see.

Comment: This is c# but I'm able to find and click the close button with xpath `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"JAModal\"]/div/div[2]/span")).Click();`

Comment: @steven01804 Hmm that looks promising but I get TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,('.//div[@id="JAModal"]//span[@alt="Close"]')).click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

I was able to solve this one through a lot of trial and error, thank you to everyone that helped!